# What do i need to have or do to install ubuntu on a windows 8 PC?

Tags: system-installation, system

I'm tempted to download and install ubuntu. Can anyone run me through the basic things I need to do or have to succesfully install and run this operating system on my PC?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes installing ubuntu alongside windows 8 can be really painful, (For me the part to get dual boot working was hard) but there are some pretty good step by step tutorials, for example you can find one here:
http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html

(If you do not have a DELL hardware you can use other backup tools, like Acronis)